# is there a way to read from a text file and store individual data as different variables?

Tags: c++

I'm working on this program:

> Create a program that will emulate an ATM machine. You must create a class named “ATM” that will have member functions that will:
>
> 1. Create a greeting on the screen,
> 2. Ask the user for a four digit pin,
>
>    a) an external file named “pin” must contain the following four pins and owner names and balances:
>
>    Larry     1234  $200
>
>    Moe       5678  $350
>
>    Lucy      0007  $600
>
>    Shirley   9876  $535
>
>    b) the pin input by the user must match one of the stored pins to allow access to transactions.
>
>    c) after 3 unsuccessful attempts, tell the user that their account is frozen and they must contact customer service.
> 3. After successful input of a pin, greet the user using their name.
> 4. Create a screen asking the user if they want to withdraw or deposit money or view their balance.
> 5. Initialize the beginning machine balance of $500. Track the balance based on deposits and withdraws.
> 6. Do not allow the user to withdraw more money than is currently in the machine.
> 7. Limit the amount of money withdrawn to $400.
> 8. The program must run on a continuous loop.

I cant figure out how to do 2b and 3. I think that I should create 4 different objects for the 4 different people, 1 line per object, then separate the name, pin, and balance within the object, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I think I should use something like `getline()` on a loop to separate the lines into the 4 objects then use `fin >> name >> pin >> balance;` to distinguish the `name`, `pin`, and `balance`, but I cant figure it out.

If I'm doing it all wrong then I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: You have the right idea. Look up `std::getline` and `std::istringstream` at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language.

Comment: You should discuss this with your teacher. That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading in from an input stream, you can basically do it like this:

```
struct User {
    std::string name;
    int pin;
    int amnt;
};
User read_user(std::istream& stream) {
    User user;
    // Reads in the username (this assumes the username doesn't contain a space)
    stream >> user.name; 
    // Reads in the pin as an integer
    stream >> user.pin;
    stream.ignore(2); //Ignore the extra space and dollar sign
    // Reads in the dollar amount as an integer
    stream >> user.amnt; 
    // Returns the user
    return user;
}
```

This will allow you to read from `std::cin` or from a filestream, and will return a user with the name, the pin, and the amount.

We can read in multiple users like this. Basically, we just call `read` multiple times.

```
std::vector<User> read_users(std::istream& stream, int n) {
    std::vector<User> users; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        users.push_back(read_user(stream)); 
    }
    return users; 
}
```

This will read in as many users as you'd like.

#### Reading in all the users in a file

We can also read in all the users in a file.

```
std::vector<User> read_all_users(std::istream& stream) {
    std::vector<User> users; 
    while(true) // Checks that there's stuff left in the stream
    {
        User u = read_user(stream); // Try reading a user
        if(not stream) break; // If there was nothing left to read, exit
        users.push_back(u); 
    }
    return users; 
}
```

#### Example usage:

We're going to open a file called `users.txt`, and read all of them in. Then, we'll print out the name, pin, and account balance of each user.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream user_file("users.txt"); 
    std::vector<User> users = read_all_users(user_file); 

    // This prints out the name, pin, and balance of each user
    for(User& user : users) {
        std::cout << "Name: " << user.name << '\n';
        std::cout << "Pin: " << user.pin << '\n';
        std::cout << "Amnt: " << user.amnt << '\n';
    }
    // Do stuff with the list of users
}
```